# Decimal to Binary Calculator

Tags: javascript

New to coding, I just thought of an idea of converting decimal numbers to binary so I made this program.

However, while I feel the logic is right, I'm not sure why its not returning a full array of zero's and 1's corresponding to the decimal number that was input.

After I get the array, I plan on doing remainder.join('') to return as one string.

If anyone could share their thoughts that would be great.

Currently it only consoles an array like ['1'] or ['0'].

```js
const getBinary = (num) => {
  let remainder = [];
  let quotient = Math.floor(num / 2);
  while (num != 0) {
    if ((quotient * 2) < num) {
      remainder.push('1');
    } else if ((quotient * 2) === num) {
      remainder.push('0');
    }
    num = Math.floor(num / 2);
    return remainder;
  }
};
console.log(getBinary(6));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You put the return statement in the while loop so it only loops once. You should place the return statement before the last `}`. Also, you should update the quotient variable in each loop.

```js
const getBinary = (num) => {

  let remainder = [];
  let quotient = Math.floor(num / 2);

  while (num != 0) {
    if ((quotient * 2) < num) {
      remainder.push('1');
    } else if ((quotient * 2) === num) {
      remainder.push('0');
    }

    num = Math.floor(num / 2);
    quotient = Math.floor(num / 2); // added this line
    // return remainder; move this line
  }
  // to there
  return remainder;

};

console.log(getBinary(6));
```